# How to make a column ParentID's value column ID's value unless ParentID column is given a value from code?

Tags: mysql, vuejs2, knex.js

I am making a basic message board system in vuejs using knexjs and mysql database, and currently working on a one tier reply.  Basically, I only need one level of replies under the parent message.  The table looks like this:

| id | board | date | user | subject | message | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 7-12-2022 | me | hello | this is a parent message | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 7-13-2022 | also_me | RE: hello | this is a reply to parent_id 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 7-13-2022 | another_board | different board | this table supports multiple boards | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 7-13-2022 | another_me | RE: hello | this is another reply | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 7-14-2022 | finally | new message | this is a new message | 5 |

In my mind the easiest way to order would be by the parent thread id, then the individual message id where board is the board I need.  The problem is the id column is auto-increment, so I have no idea how to code it to where if parent_id is not given, give it the id column value.

Comment: Something like `ORDER BY IFNULL(parent_id, id)` or `ORDER BY IF(parent_id=0, id)` or similar. Note that this is not efficient.

Comment: @barrycarter How could I make it more efficient?  I'm willing to change my thought process if needed.

Comment: When someone adds a new record, could you set an existing or new column to be the value you want to sort on? If you control the code, that's easy. If you control the db, you could try `CREATE TRIGGER`. If you control neither, I don't see an easy solution

Comment: @barrycarter I control coding.  Maybe I am overthinking this, but I need replies to be under parent message and ordering by just id or another column will put replies in oder as they come.

Comment: You can insert in two steps - insert the record and if parent_id was null, get the insert id and then update the record.

Comment: Otherwise you can handle this in your select statement using `IFNULL()`, rather than in the `ORDER BY` statement.